# Typeahead calling functions .val .open .close etc throws errors

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am struggling to call typeahead.js functions like `val`, `open`, `close`, etc.

The typeahead works properly on the input element as it displays the entries but when I try to call any typeahead function I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: one of local, prefetch, or remote is requiredmessage: "one of local, prefetch, or remote is required
```

My init code is as follows:

```
var currentMedicalAid;

var medicalAidList = $('#medicalAidList');


var medicalAidengine = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('MedicalAid1'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 5,
    prefetch: {
        url: '/api/Search/GetMedicalAidList',
    }
});


medicalAidengine.initialize();


medicalAidList.typeahead(null, {
    name: 'MedicalAid1',
    displayKey: 'MedicalAid1',
    // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
    // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
    source: medicalAidengine.ttAdapter()
}).blur(function () {
    match = false;
    for (var i = medicalAidengine.index.datums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ($(this).val() == medicalAidengine.index.datums[i].MedicalAid1) {
            currentMedicalAid = medicalAidengine.index.datums[i].MedicalAidID;
            match = true;
        }
    };
    if (!match) {
        currentMedicalAid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
        $(this).val('');
        medicalAidList.typeahead('val', ''); // throws error
    }
});;
```

Everytime I run either one of these functions, I get an error:

```
medicalAidList.typeahead('val', '');
or
$('#medicalAidList').typeahead('val','');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is "/api/Search/GetMedicalAidList" returning? Is this JSON? Can you check whether this request is executing successfully in your browser. Also including an example of the JSON returned will help.

Comment: The JSON is perfect because the list works. It doesn't have anything to do with the actual typeahead working, because it works perfectly. When i type in the dropdown i get a list appearing as it should. I just cannot access the typeahead functions - i have the same problem on all my type aheads (some use remote others local, just cannot access the type ahead.

Comment: Ok. I asked my question as typeahead requires an array of javascript objects for it's datums, not JSON objects. Your example is missing a "filter" function in the "prefetch" declaration. See this example https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#prefetch.

Answer (score 1):

The `initialize` method is asynchronous. It is possible that some of your code are running when the Bloodhound engine is not fully initialized. You might need to wrap the rest of your code in a callback:

```
// initialize returns a jQuery promise, so we can call its done method
medicalAidengine.initialize().done(function(){

// Rest of your code

})
```

Comment: Although this is correct it is not relevant to my question. The typeahead works correctly its is just not possible to execute its methods.